# How is the Lai-Massey scheme invertible?

Tags: block-cipher

The Wikipedia page on the subject and other descriptions that I can find of it are as clear as mud. $L$ and $R$ are combined to make a number that is then added to both. That seems like a loss of information to me.

Answer (score 2):

One Lai-Massey round can be described as 
$$
\begin{align}
L' &= \sigma(L \oplus F_k(L \oplus R)) \\
R' &= R \oplus F_k(L \oplus R)\,,
\end{align}
$$
where $F_k$ is some round function—not necessarily invertible—and $\sigma(\cdot)$ is an orthomorphism, an arbitrary function such that both $\sigma(x)$ and $\sigma'(x) = \sigma(x) \oplus x$ are invertible.

To invert this,
$$
\begin{align}
L &= \sigma^{-1}(L') \oplus F_k(\sigma^{-1}(L') \oplus R') \\
R &= R' \oplus F_k(\sigma^{-1}(L') \oplus R')\,.
\end{align}
$$
We can see this works because
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^{-1}(L') &= 
L \oplus F_k(L \oplus R)\,,
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^{-1}(L') \oplus R' &= 
L \oplus F_k(L \oplus R) \oplus R \oplus F_k(L \oplus R) \\
&= L \oplus R\,.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Does $\sigma(\cdot)$ have to be applied to $L$? Can be applied to both $L$ and $R$?

Comment: Only applied to $L$.

Comment: But can it be applied to $R$, too?

Comment: Yes, but only one or the other, not both.

Comment: Why can't it be applied to both?

Comment: Using the information in the answer go through and apply it to both and see what happens. That will also help you understand the answer better.

Comment: @kodlu I don't know what an orthomorphism is.

Comment: You can use as a common example of an orthomorphism $(L_0, L_1) \mapsto (L_1, L_0 \oplus L_1)$, where $L_0, L_1$ are the two halves of $L$.

Comment: Can $L$ and $R$ be modified with two functions? Like, say, Threefish's mix function and its mirror opposite?